# Comparison of PassByVal, PassByRef, and PassByConstRef of std::shared_ptr (What can(cannot) be changed)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptrStr(new std::string("One"));

// increases the reference count to std::string("One") by one after entering the function
// decreases the reference count to std::string("One") by one before exiting the function
void PassByValue(std::shared_ptr<std::string> msg)
{
    msg->clear();                              // clears the string pointed by ptrStr
    msg.reset(new std::string("hello world")); // doesn't change the value of ptrStr
                                               // because it only changes a local copy of ptrStr
                                               // which will be destroyed when the function is returned.
                                               // Note the msg, the local copy of ptrStr, points to the same
                                               // resource where ptrStr points to.
}

// doesn't affect the reference count
void PassByReference(std::shared_ptr<std::string> &msg)
{
    msg->clear();                              // clears the string pointed by ptrStr
    msg.reset(new std::string("hello world")); // does change the value of ptrStr
}

// doesn't affect the reference count
void PassByConstReference(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& msg)
{
    msg->clear();                              // clears the string pointed by ptrStr
    msg.reset(new std::string("hello world")); // compilation errors
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Each time only one of the following three lines is executed
    //PassByValue(ptrStr);
    //PassByReference(ptrStr);
    //PassByConstReference(ptrStr)

    std::cout << *ptrStr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I am NOT arguing which passing mechanism is good or bad here. I ONLY want to understand the consequence of different passing mechanism of `std::shared_ptr` and ONLY want to focus on pass `std::shared_ptr` as a function parameter.

**Question1**> Please help read the comments and correct me if I am wrong

**Question2**> Is it true that no matter which mechanism you choose, you can always change the resource pointed by the `std::shared_ptr`?

**Question3**> Is it true that `std::shared_ptr` is similar as other function parameters and play similar behavior regarding PassByValue, PassByReference, and PassByConstReference.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question1> Please help read the comments and correct me if I am wrong

According to my understanding, your comments are correct.

> Question2> Is it true that no matter which mechanism you choose, you can always change the resource pointed by the std::shared_ptr?

Well, sort of. You can always retrieve the raw pointer from a `std::shared_pointer`. When you pass it as `const` you'll get a `const` raw pointer. If you'd manipulate the contents of the pointed object, you'll get compilation errors. But there are ways to transform a `const` pointer to a *normal* pointer, e.g with `const_cast`.

> Question3> Is it true that std::shared_ptr is similar as other function parameters and play similar behavior regarding PassByValue, PassByReference, and PassByConstReference.

From the C++ point of view, `std::shared_pointer`s are just types as any other one, so no, no difference here regarding the method of argument passing.

Comment: For Q2, I mean to do it by following the rules rather than use any tricks.

Comment: The raw pointer which is retrieved from a `std::shared_ptr<std::string> const` will always have type `std::string*`. It will neither be const, nor point to const.

Comment: @q0987: The `const_cast` is (unfortunately) no trick and part of the C++ specification. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/const_cast)

Answer (score 2):

1. All your comments are entirely correct.
2. You could pass by `std::shared_ptr<std::string const>`. In this case the resource pointed to by the `shared_ptr` would not be changeable.
3. I am not sure what you are asking, but the rules for argument passing do not have special cases for `std::shared_ptr`.